# Bandwidth exhausted

Tags: google-cloud-functions

```
Error: Bandwidth exhausted
at Http2CallStream.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/common/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:96)
at Http2CallStream.emit (events.js:327)
at Http2CallStream.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482)
at (/usr/src/app/common/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:71)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79)
```

I have received this error, you can help me resolve, I tried to increase the quota google log but it doesn't affect. And I also have a question about this error related to my side or google log side and how to resolve it?

Comment: This error indeed, indicates that you are going above the quotas set in your project. Have you checked in your [quotas page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?service=cloudfunctions.googleapis.com&usage=ALL&project=_&_ga=2.4619059.1814092611.1601357388-387989268.1584431183) which of the quotas are you surpassing? Besides that, please, provide more detaisl on environment, frameworks you are using, what your functions are performing etc., so it's possible to have a better understanding.

Comment: I'm checked but can see the quota related to the bandwidth. sorry about my question that it's not clearly. I'm using Google Cloud Logging and using for logging my server. Do you need more information? hope you have some resolve for me. For now, I have no idea